# Firebase JWT does not work with Python and UID JWT

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jwt, firebase-authentication

Why?

```
import requests
import json
from firebase_token_generator import create_token
auth_payload = { "uid": "BAD-BAD-BAD-KEY"}
CREDENTIAL = create_token("my-secret-key", auth_payload)


payload = json.dumps({"dude":"me"})
path = "/test1/test.json"
url = "https://omgfirebase.firebaseio.com%s?auth=%s" % (path,CREDENTIAL)
print url
print payload
r = requests.put(url, data=payload)

print r.status_code
print r.text

{"dude": "me"}
200
```

If I use a bad invalid uid, I can still write to the database. Why? The data is in Firebase Database.

Comment: A uid is a value that uniquely identifies a user. There is no such thing as an "invalid uid".

Comment: its a bad if I can write with a UID that is not valid

Comment: When you use custom authentication, Firebase has no knowledge of the users except for what you tell it. So any UID you pass it is inherently valid.